# Scan compiled classes with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, bytecode

I want to create SBT-task to generate documentation for my classes based on annotations inside these classes.

So I am creating a task:

```
val genToolsDocs = TaskKey[Unit]("gendoc-tools", "gen doc")

genToolsDocs in Runtime <<=
(compile in Compile) map {

  (compiled: Analysis) ⇒ {
    ???
  }

}
```

But then I actually don't now how to properly get generated classes from this `compiled: Analysis` object?

there is `compiled.apis.internal.values.map(_.api()...)` from where I can get some info about my classes, but not too much.

there are also `compiled.relations.classes` and `compiled.stamps.allBinaries` and many other things but I can't understand what should I use to get compiled class files.

Maybe it is fully wrong way, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've ended up with

```
genToolsDocs <<= (compile in Compile) map {
  (compiled: Analysis) ⇒ {
    val files = compiled.stamps.allProducts.filter(_.getPath.contains(???))
    ???
  }
}
```

and in `files` now I get all my compiled classes.